# why if any line fail inside a afterAll() or beforeAll() does not fail test or log anything?

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I have intentionally written errored code in a afterEach block and executed it but I see the block is executing silently and marking tests as passed. How to capture failures in afterAll() block?

Comment: so error is in `afterEach` but you want to capture it in `afterAll`? if so, your header says different

Comment: No, I need to do that calculation in afterAll() itself, but I see failures are penetrating silently.

Comment: I just tested and I can see errors from afterall. Attach what you have in there and might be able to help you